# Itext set vertical position for a table header

Tags: java, itext

Is there a way to set the vertical position back to a certain point in Itext?

The spacing from the previous page is using blanks in the new page how can i set the header in the new page at vertical position 764??

```
if(verticalPosition - bottom <= bottom){ 
    /*two blank lines after this*/
    PdfPTable tableHeader = new PdfPTable(1);
    tableHeader.setWidthPercentage(100); cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CMHSP: " + tr,ReportConstants.reportFontBold));
    cell.setBorder(0);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(cell.ALIGN_LEFT);
    tableHeader.addCell(cell);
```

Comment: Can you share some code to help make your question clearer?

Comment: @winhowes: 'if(verticalPosition - bottom <= bottom){ /*two blank lines after this*/PdfPTable tableHeader = new PdfPTable(1);     tableHeader.setWidthPercentage(100); cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CMHSP: " + tr,ReportConstants.reportFontBold));           cell.setBorder(0);              cell.setHorizontalAlignment(cell.ALIGN_LEFT);          tableHeader.addCell(cell);